# react native app is crashing with no logs when uploading image on ios

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, expo, firebase-storage

when i try to use firebase uploadBytes on android it works fin but on ios whenever the video file is bigger than 2 mb the application crashes with no logs
i tried using uploadBytesResumable and even tried to downgrade my firebase version to version 8 and no solution yet

```
const fetchImage = await fetch(localUri);
const imageBlob = await fetchImage.blob();
const storage = getStorage();
const upload = ref(storage, 'path_to_sotrage');
const uploadTask = await uploadBytesResumable(upload, imageBlob);
return await getDownloadURL(uploadTask.ref);
```

Comment: The `uploadBytesResumable()` does not return a Promise so await is unnecessary there. Have you tried using `uploadBytes()` instead?

Comment: Have you found a solution yet? Facing same issues here & android crashes without uploading even.

Answer (score 0):

This `uploadBytes` crashes for me and I couldn't figure out why. However, `uploadBytesResumable` pattern from [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files) is working and seems more stable. Hope it helps.

```js
import { getStorage, ref, uploadBytesResumable, getDownloadURL } from "firebase/storage";

const storage = getStorage();

// Create the file metadata
/** @type {any} */
const metadata = {
  contentType: 'image/jpeg'
};

// Upload file and metadata to the object 'images/mountains.jpg'
const storageRef = ref(storage, 'images/' + file.name);
const uploadTask = uploadBytesResumable(storageRef, file, metadata);

// Listen for state changes, errors, and completion of the upload.
uploadTask.on('state_changed',
  (snapshot) => {
    // Get task progress, including the number of bytes uploaded and the total number of bytes to be uploaded
    const progress = (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;
    console.log('Upload is ' + progress + '% done');
    switch (snapshot.state) {
      case 'paused':
        console.log('Upload is paused');
        break;
      case 'running':
        console.log('Upload is running');
        break;
    }
  }, 
  (error) => {
    // A full list of error codes is available at
    // https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/handle-errors
    switch (error.code) {
      case 'storage/unauthorized':
        // User doesn't have permission to access the object
        break;
      case 'storage/canceled':
        // User canceled the upload
        break;

      // ...

      case 'storage/unknown':
        // Unknown error occurred, inspect error.serverResponse
        break;
    }
  }, 
  () => {
    // Upload completed successfully, now we can get the download URL
    getDownloadURL(uploadTask.snapshot.ref).then((downloadURL) => {
      console.log('File available at', downloadURL);
    });
  }
);
```